# NiFi custom processor expression language

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-nifi

I'm trying to make a custom processor in Apache NiFi that can add an attribute/string to the JSON object in the flowfile content. At the moment it works when I just use a string but it's not working when I use NiFi's expression language although I have it supported in my code.

The expression language is 100% correct as it works in another processor and I've also tried different attributes to make sure it's not the attribute.

The property:

```
public static final PropertyDescriptor ADD_ATTRIBUTE = new PropertyDescriptor
        .Builder().name("Add Attribute")
        .description("Example Property")
        .required(true)
        .addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_EMPTY_VALIDATOR)
        .expressionLanguageSupported(true)
        .build();
```

Later in my code when I want to get the value and put in the JSON object I use:

```
jsonObject.put("hostname", context.getProperty(ADD_ATTRIBUTE).evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue());
```

I also made a Unit Test and it works when I assign a text value to the testrunner.setProperty. However I don't know how I can assign an attribute to the testrunner or how I can use expression language in my test.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or a solution!

Comment: What is the return value you get from "context.getProperty(ADD_ATTRIBUTE).evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue()"?

Comment: Do you need anything from the input flowfile in evaluating your expression?  If so be sure to pass the flowfile into the evaluateAttributeExpressions() call.

Comment: Hi the return value is an empty string when I use expression language. When I just use a regular string, for example just "test", then the return value is "test".  I don't need anything but also tried that to see if it did anything but it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll put my answer from [Hortonworks Community Connection](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/22448/apache-nifi-custom-processor-expression-language.html) here too FWIW:

If the expression refers to attributes on a flow file, you will need to pass a reference to the flow file into evaluateAttributeExpressions:

```
FlowFile flowFile = session.get();
jsonObject.put("hostname", context.getProperty(ADD_ATTRIBUTE).evaluateAttributeExpressions(flowFile).getValue());
```

If the property contains an attribute name (rather than an Expression containing an attribute name) and you want the value from the flow file:

```
jsonObject.put("hostname", flowFile.getAttribute(context.getProperty(ADD_ATTRIBUTE).getValue()));
```

If the attribute value itself contains Expression Language and you want to evaluate it, take a look at the following class:

```
org.apache.nifi.attribute.expression.language.Query
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding testing...

Assuming you are evaluating the expression language against an incoming FlowFile (evaluateAttributeExpressions(flowFile)) then you can do the following:

`runner.setProperty(ADD_ATTRIBUTE, "${my.attribute}");`

Then create an attribute Map that has my.attribute in it:

`final Map<String,String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
 attributes.put("my.attribute", myAttribute);`

Then enqueue some content with the attributes:

`runner.enqueue(fileIn, attributes);
runner.run();`

An example from the code base:

https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/1e56de9521e4bc0752b419ffc7d62e096db1c389/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-solr-bundle/nifi-solr-processors/src/test/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/solr/TestPutSolrContentStream.java#L243